# Write a function to return diagonal elements of an array(NxN) as an array in python

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
#getting number of rows and columns for the arrat
nr=input("enter rows")
nc=input("enter columns")
print("Please enter same rows and columns")
n=nr*nc
ar1=[]
#checking for square matrix
if(nr==nc):
#loop to append elements into the empty-list ar1
  for i in range(n):
     ele=input("enter elements")
     ar1.append(ele)
#getting the number of rows of array1
array1=np.array(ar1).shape
#function to get the diagonal elements of array
def diagonal(a):
  global n
  n=str(n)
  for i in n:
     for j in n:
       if i==j:

          newarr=np.array(a[i][j])

  #print(newarr) 
diagonal(array1)
```

newarr=np.array(a[i][j]) is resulting in an error showing:
   #TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str for below code

Comment: Isn't the error clear? Why don't you fix this (pretty obvious) issue first? Also consider a [mcve], if you're not clear where they come from and how to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your matrix is going to be a square one, you need not take the row and column input separately. You can just take the value n. Your diagonal function will then look like :

```
newa=[]
def diag(arr):
    for i,a in enumerate(arr):
        newa[i]=arr[i,i]
```

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @Gautam, by the way here's a workaround solution which uses inbuilt `diagonal` function:

```
lst = []
size = int(input('Enter size of sqaure matrix'))
for i in range(1, (size**2)+1):
    lst.append(int(input('Enter ' + str(i) +'th element')))
lst

Enter size of sqaure matrix2
Enter 1th element5
Enter 2th element6
Enter 3th element8
Enter 4th element7
[5, 6, 8, 7]

arr = np.array(lst).reshape(size,size)
arr.diagonal()

[5, 7]
```